# Why is React v16.8.5 Not Rendering Some Objects

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting some information and placing in my react state. I can log the data in the react state but no output is appearing in my display for the `{singleEmployee}` ... Could this be a bug in react v16.8.5

```
import React from 'react';
var Airtable = require('airtable');
var base = new Airtable({apiKey: ''}).base('');

class Firm extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  name:props.location.firm.firmName,
  year:props.location.firm.yearFounded,
  address:props.location.firm.officeAddress,
  website:props.location.firm.website,
  aum:props.location.firm.aum,
  check:props.location.firm.checkSize,       
  employees:props.location.firm.employees,
  focus:props.location.firm.detailedFirmSpecialisations, 
  loaded:false,
  employeesInfo:null,   
};
}

componentDidMount(){    
const ids = this.state.employees
const employeesInfo = [];
ids.forEach((id)=>{
  base('EmploymentHistory').find(id, (err, record)=>{
    if (err) { 
      console.error(err); 
      return; 
    } 
    employeesInfo.push({
      name:record.get('Employment ID'),
      job:record.get('Job Title'),
      investment:record.get('Investment lookup'),
      dateStarted: `${record.get('Start Month (1-12)')} ${record.get('Start Year')}`    
    })
  })
})
console.log(employeesInfo)
this.setState({
  employeesInfo:employeesInfo,
  loaded:false
},()=>
  this.setState({
    loaded:true
  })
)  
}

render() {  
const {name,year,address,website,aum,check,focus,employeesInfo,loaded} = this.state;
{loaded && console.log(employeesInfo)}
const singleEmployee = employeesInfo && employeesInfo.map(employee=>{
  return <h4 key={employee.name}> Name is {employee.name}</h4>
})

if(!loaded){
  return(
    <div>loading...</div>
  )
}
return (
  <div>
    <h2>{name ? name : 'N/A'} Audit Report</h2>
    <h4>Year Founded {year ? year : 'N/A'}</h4>
    <h4>Address {address ? address : 'N/A'}</h4>
    <h4>Website {website ? website : 'N/A'}</h4>
    <h4>AUM {aum ? aum : 'N/A'}</h4>
    <h4>Cheque Size {check ? check : 'N/A'}</h4>
    <h4>Investment Focus {focus ? focus : 'N/A'}</h4>
    <h2>Employees</h2>
    {singleEmployee}
  </div>
); 
} 
}
```

Comment: Please show the value of `employeesInfo`

Comment: It looks like `employeesInfo` is an object, but you're iterating over it with `map` as though it were an array

Comment: it is an array...check whole code

Comment: Are you trying to write out the list of all employees because is not clear where you're finding the employee you're interested in.

Comment: You should add some outputs and more explanations on what you want to do and how.

Comment: I am guessing that employeesInfo returned from another thread so it got empty when the app render. maybe you can try adding it to state and will see

Comment: The employees Info is in the state that's as seen in the componentDidMount @duc mai

Comment: I meant this function base('EmploymentHistory').find where you push more item inside that and this function running asynchronously so it does not affect to the render

Answer (score 0):

Since `employeesInfo` is an array you will need to take an item by index e.g.

```
const singleEmployee = employeesInfo && (<h4 key={employeesInfo[0].name}> Name is {employeesInfo[0].name}</h4>)
```

the code you have here:

```
const singleEmployee = employeesInfo && employeesInfo.map(employee=>{
  return <h4 key={employee.name}> Name is {employee.name}</h4>
})
```

Will store an array of react elements in `singleEmployee`, not a single item

It looks like what you should be doing is finding the element in `employeesInfo` first, but you don't have an id for it.

I made a fiddle for you with a simpler version of what you're trying to achieve: 
https://jsfiddle.net/9L8u7fex/

Comment: It's now just printing `Name is` without the employees name...and employeesInfo is an array of employee objects

Comment: what does console.log(employeesInfo) return?

Comment: it logs an array of all employees in the array ie. `0: {name: "Else Thomson (1969)", job: Array(1), investment: Array(1), dateStarted: "6 2005"}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)`

Comment: Yeah sure, so the problem is you're trying to write out a single employee record, when you actually have an array of them.

Comment: I am mapping over the array here `employeesInfo.map(employee=>{
  return <h4 key={employee.name}> Name is {employee.name}</h4>
})`

Comment: sure, so are you trying to write out a list of all employees? because if so, the name of `singleEmployee` is deceiving

Comment: do you have the `id` of the user you're trying to find passed into your component anywhere, that may help.

Comment: yeah I am listing all employees. Like passing the id as a key... it doesn't work

Comment: I have uploaded the code... I'm getting the data from airtable and passing it as props

Comment: I have checked out the fiddle and made the changes on the code. However I haven't seen any change

Answer (score 0):

I think the code to render employInfo does not have any problem. The problem you are suffering here is about the way you push more values to the array which running asynchronously. I would suggest you to save the list in state.

you can refer to my sample on sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/0v3xo8p4yp. if you comment out setTemp which is actually to trigger a new rendering after I update the list only. If you comment this code out the new list will never be appeared in the dom. I think it is quite similar to your problem

Comment: Do you have an explanation that doesn't use react hooks

Comment: do you mean my sample? as I explained in my answer I used hook to trigger rerender only and I commented out it in my code show that the new list is not being rendered. If you uncomment it out then you will see the new list is rendered